# Performing Calculation In Gridview itemtemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to perform calculation in a `GridView`:

```
NetAmount = (ServiceAmount * Quantity) * Discount
```

I had written code in `RowDataBound` but it's not working. Can someone help me solve this problem? I would appreciate if some one share their knowledge.

my Aspx code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Height="156px" Width="618px"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderWidth="1px" 
    HorizontalAlign="Justify" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" 
    BackColor="LightGoldenrodYellow" BorderColor="Tan" CellPadding="2" 
    ForeColor="Black" GridLines="None" onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand"> 

    <FooterStyle BackColor="Tan" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" ForeColor="DarkSlateBlue" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="DarkSlateBlue" ForeColor="GhostWhite" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#FFFFC4" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#BF6000"/>
        <Columns>
            <!-- snip -->
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Net Amt">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtNetAmt" ReadOnly="true" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="#BF6000" runat="server" Width="55px"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" />
</asp:GridView>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function CalcSercode(ServiceAmount,Quantity, Discount,NetAmount)
    {
        var Quantity=parseFloat(document.getElementById(Quantity).value);
        var Discount= parseFloat(document.getElementById(Discount).value);
        var ServiceAmount=document.getElementById(ServiceAmount);
        var SerAmountValue = parseFloat((ServiceAmount * Quantity)-((ServiceAmount  *Quantity)*Discount/100));
        //var SellPriceValueRound = Math.round(SellPriceValue,4);
        var SerAmountValueRound = SerAmountValue;
        ServiceAmount.innerHTML= SerAmountValueRound ;
    }
</script>
```

---

My cs code :

```
//TextBox TxtServiceCode =  GridView1.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("TxtServiceCode") as TextBox;
//DataSet dss = new DataSet();
//SqlConnection MyConnection = new SqlConnection("server=prog; database=mydatabase;UID=sa;PWD=naco123;");
//SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("select * from [ServiceCode]",  MyConnection);
//SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
//DataSet ds = new DataSet();
//adp.Fill(ds);
//GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
//GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Can you isolate the problem using a debugger, and specify it?

Comment: thaks for the reply sir,my datarowcommand is not firing and my javascript is also not working suggest me sir......

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that calculation with inline databinding syntax:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <%# ((Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("ServiceAmount")) * Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Quantity"))) * Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("Discount"))).ToString("C") %>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply sir,my datarowcommand is not firing is this code correct please correct the code and the javascript.....

Answer (score 0):

In general, I would advise you to do this calculation not at the frontend but either in a business layer or as in your case, you do not seem to have one and go straight for the database.

So wy not add the NetAmount=(ServiceAmount*Quantity)*Discount to your select statement. If you do so, you can simply databind that column to your Grid since it is anyway readonly

Comment: thanks for the reply sir,i am performing the calculations at the client side can you explore above above concept........

Comment: yes, but you have business logic in javascript - that will be difficult to maintain and if they do not have javascript enabled it will not work at all. So this is the wrong place to perform them.